# How to use Tinyscrollbar?

Tags: jquery, tinyscrollbar

I'm a little confused how to use the tinyscrollbar plugin, I try to use it like this:

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum ...
</div>

$('div').tinyscrollbar();​
```

but get an exception, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/Kgt7c/. The source looks like it can't find the viewport object it searches by class:

```
oViewport   = { obj: $( '.viewport', root ) }
```

and I don't see any code that creates this element. Do I have to provide a bunch of elements (e.g. 'viewport', 'scrollbar' etc.) to use this plugin? Has anyone got this running?

Comment: I was able to remove the errors, and this should get you closer, the scroll bar still is appearing though: http://jsfiddle.net/Kgt7c/22/

Answer (score 3):

Got it to work http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/Kgt7c/25/ you really have to include the additional markup...

```
  <div id="scrollbar1">
    <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div>            </div></div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
          (...)

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include divs for scrollbar, track, and thumb, and give them height attributes in css. Also include viewport and overview divs:

```
<div id="scroll">                                                                
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <div class="track">
            <div class="thumb">
                <div class="end"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
     <div class="viewport">                                                                                             </div>
         <div class="overview"> 
             Content here
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then, call:

```
 $('#scroll').tinyscrollbar();
```